# Nested Map iterators

Tags: c++, csv, dictionary, vector, binary-search-tree

I have the following code:

```
    int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int,int> monthMap;
    typedef std::map<int,std::map<int, monthMap>> yearMap;


    //std::ifstream inputFile("MetData-31-3.csv");
    //std::ifstream inputFile("MetData_Mar01-2015-Mar01-2016-ALL.csv");
    //if(!inputFile) return -1;

    //readFile(inputFile, yearMap);
    int year = 2011, month = 4;
    yearMap ym;
    monthMap mm;
    ym[year][month];
    yearMap::iterator yearItr = ym.find(year);

    if(yearItr != ym.end())
    {
        //monthMap &mp = yearItr->second;
        monthMap::iterator monthItr;
        monthItr = (yearItr->second).find(month);
        if(monthItr != yearItr->second.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Found!";
        }
    }

}
```

Essentially what i'm trying to do is setup the base for my project, reading in from a CSV file that contains information such as date, time, windspeeds and radiation levels from a data centre.

I've got everything working as a vector in my other project however i'm required to switch data structures and implement a BST and a Map within the project.

My design strategy is this:
Have a Map of years
which contains a map of months
which contains a BST of days
which contains a vector of WindData objects
which contains all the elements such as windspeed, time, radiation etc.

First of all, is this the best way to set things up? I can't really think of an alternative at this stage.

But my main issue i'm running into here is how to actually iterate through the nested map, i'm getting the following error from this code

```
D:\Projects\testProj\main.cpp|31|error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::map<int, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >}' and 'std::map<int, std::map<int, int> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, int> > >}')|
```

This all seems very bulky, ugly and slow to me to use this data structure for this type of process but i am required to do it, I'm open to any suggestions for a different method of storing and processing this data given i'm still using both MAP & BST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
monthMap::iterator monthItr;
monthItr = (yearItr->second).find(month);
```

To:

```
std::map<int, monthMap>::iterator monthItr;
monthItr = (yearItr->second).find(month);
```

However, AAA would save your time and effort:

```
int main(){
    typedef std::map<int,int> monthMap;
    typedef std::map<int,std::map<int, monthMap>> yearMap;

    int year = 2011, month = 4;
    yearMap ym;
    monthMap mm;
    ym[year][month];
    auto yearItr = ym.find(year);
    if(yearItr != ym.end()){
        auto monthItr = (yearItr->second).find(month);
        if(monthItr != yearItr->second.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Found!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Do you have any suggestions to how i've setup these data structures?
Will this work having a BST inside the Month map for days and a vector inside each day BST?

Comment: Your design is broken IMO. too many nested map is not the best option. You should re think about a better way.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to do this for about 2 weeks now and this is the only solution I can logically come up with that uses both BST and Map to store this data.

Comment: I've updated my code a bit but running into some more issues.

I've decided to ditch the vector all together and instead keep it as a Map of years containing a map of months containing a map of days containing a BST of WindData objects, sorted by time.

My problem is with insertion

Comment: Can't read code

Quick version:
 logTree lg;
lg.insert(windspeed);

 ym[d.getYear()][d.getMonth()][d.getDay()] = lg;

Comment: @MichaelBell In SO you should ask a separate question rather than comment with your question. You will find many people that are glad to help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask